# Does Eclipse install in C drive?

Tags: java, windows, eclipse, ide, installation

I have a question that might be a little stupid. I am changing from Netbeans to Eclipse and I noticed that Eclipse doesn't install on my C: drive, nor come up on the start menu, or come up on the remove programs window. When I run the installation it just opens up, and I have to use it from that file.

Am I using it wrong? Or is it supposed to be like that? If not, how to I properly install eclipse? thanks.

Comment: this is not programming related question!!!!

Comment: There is tag called eclipse. `eclipse` is not a programming language :). You can ask `tech` questions here

Comment: upvote for this question :(

Comment: @Sahal - I completely agree :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to extract the archive to the root of `C:\` drive, thus creating the folder `C:\eclipse`, or just moved the extracted eclipse folder to the root of `C:\` drive if you extracted it already. Since Eclipse does not have any installer, there will be a file inside the Eclipse folder named `eclipse.exe`. You can double click on the file to run Eclipse.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I'm going to do, and then create a shortcut in the desktop for easy access. Thanks!

Comment: yes, i'm also did this. i have created a shortcut in the desktop for easy access.

Answer (score 6):

> Am I using it wrong? Or is it supposed to be like that? If not, how to I properly install eclipse? thanks.

Eclipse is not supposed to be installed. On Windows download zip-file, unzip it and run eclipse.exe that's it.

Comment: Oh ok I figured, it's just since netbeans does install, I thought I was doing something wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Simply unzip the Eclipse download anywhere that's convenient for you.  Then browse down under the "eclipse/" root folder and execute "eclipse.exe" (on Windows).

You can also "right-click, send to, Desktop" Eclipse.exe to make it easier to start.

As simple as that :)

PS:

Be sure to install the Java JDK first:

- http://java.com

Answer (score 0):

That means you have not installed eclipse. The one you are using is `already installed` one. - In windows you don't need to install it. Download a zip file and use it.